# show stack trace in yii framework

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

we get stack trace when an error occurs in the execution, like in the following picture .

[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f9Mq.gif)

I would like to see this tracing at the bottom of the page every time I executes a page. ( even without errors) so that I can find out what are the pages ran and what is happening inside the framework

How can I activate this ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "stack trace" doesn't make much sense outside of an error scenario, but you can see what Yii is up to by enabling the debug mode. In your index.php add

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
```

and in the `log` component of your main Yii configuration array (config/main.php), add this array under the `routes` component:

```
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                'enabled' => YII_DEBUG,
            ),
```

This should show you what you want.

Make sure to remove the `YII_DEBUG` line from your production code!

Comment: Thanks but I would like to get more details.

Comment: More details on what specifically?

Comment: Remember to add the `defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);` line _before_ including yii.php or yiilite.php.

Comment: How should I get this in Yii2 ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of tracing information available in the Yii debug toolbar: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-debug-toolbar/

Might be what you are after

Answer (score 2):

You can open these line of code in your project `config/main.php`

```
'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages

             array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),

        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you defined the file log routing in the config file, you can see the logs in the log file stored in runtime directory.

File log routing is defined like this:

```
...
'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'trace, info',
                    'categories'=>'system.*',
                ),
         )
```